# How do I export multiple pages of a CorelDraw file at once?

Tags: export, gif, coreldraw

I have a CorelDraw X6 .cdr file that contains multiple images, each on a separate page. I want to export the image from each of these pages to produce a set of GIFs, however the CorelDraw Export option in the File menu only allows you to export one page at a time (when using anything other than the .eps option), making for a very slow and difficult export process. To use this menu option to export these images to GIF, JPEG, PNG, etc. could take hours of clicking through menus. How can I export all of these images at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export multiple pages (in CorelDraw X6), complete the following steps:

1. Select **Tools -> Macros -> Run Macros**.
2. Find the **Macros in** dropdown and select **FileConverter**. If you do not see this option, use the Macro Manager to download it first.
3. Select **Converter.Start** and then click **Run**.
4. Enter (or select using the dialog) the file you wish to process using the **Source** field.
5. Enter (or select using the dialog) a destination folder for the output using the **Destination** field.
6. Select your desired output format using the **Convert to** field.
7. Select **Save each page as a separate file**.
8. Review any other options on this panel and then click **Convert**.